# Exporting jar from eclipse with classpaths...How do you do it?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, classpath

How do you properly export jar file from eclipse with all the class path dependencies?

**I have the following scenario:**
I have class A that uses class B - all are part of the same project.  When I run the project everything works just fine since everything is on the path.

Now... after exporting class A using Export>>Jar File>> option in eclipse, I obviously get an error when running class A since .jar can not find class B.    The solution that I found is to explicitly include both files into one single jar.  But I think it is not the best and ideal solution.  I think the better solution would be to export class A as jar and have a classpath for class B...

Is it possible to include the classpaths through eslipse's 'export jar' option?  if so, then could someone outline the steps?

Thanks!!

P.S. I saw some similar posts on here, but none outline the solution explicitly and exactly. So please if mark this post as a 'dup' make sure you provide the link to the post that answers my question exactly and completely with the solution that works.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a self-contained JAR file, do

File->Export->Runnable JAR file (from Java section)

It will prompt you for existing launch configuration, and will package all necessary dependencies into the uber-jar.

I would only use this option as a one-off quick-and-dirty solution, and for production would use a build management system, such as Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Thanks!!  I tried this approach - this works, but the packaged .jar now includes all subfolders and classes that I do not need at all but are found in the project .  
is it possible to just include the references to the classes that are needed by calling class only?

Comment: As I said, there is no substitution for the build and dependency management tools.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander!  I have never worked with dependency management tools; hence, was hoping that can 'cut corners'.  Which one would you recommend the best for the newbies out of those two you mentioned previously?  Thanks again,

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no dependency management tools for the newbies.  That said, I would start with Maven.

Comment: I will check out Maven.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the whole project, not just this one class. Right click on the Project in the Solution Explorer, then Export

Comment: This could work,  the only thing is the entire project is over couple gigabytes,